# Restrict Duplicate Value in DataGrid View in C# from Listview?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

**Using a ListView Control to add row in to DataGridView On MouseDoubleClick_event
The Rows are Getting Added To the DataGrid But It also adds The Duplicate rows as well.
Is there a Way To handel duplicate values**

```
   ArrayList arrListChkIDs = new ArrayList();
        if (dgvPriceView.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dgvPriceView.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                arrListChkIDs.Add(dgvPriceView.Rows[i].Cells["Code"].Value);
            }

        }
```

> Getting Unique Value In array List to compare With My ListView Value
>   Now How Should I Compare It??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Hey Now Its Pretty Simple From Here***

```
ArrayList arrListChkIDs = new ArrayList();
//Now Get and Check The Code from List View or put the Index Number  at subItems
string Code = listView.SelectedItems[0].SubItems["Code"].Text;
if (!arrListChkIDs.Contains(Code))
{

}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Row Already Exist!",
                    MessageBoxButtons.OK, 
                    MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    return;
}
```